# Query on snmp trap size

Tags: udp, ip, snmp, snmp-trap

In our application, buffer is allocated to receive snmp trap which is:

```
unsigned char buffer[65536 - 60 - 8];
```

But these numbers tell me about the IP packet header, footer and total length.

Can you please explain, why do we need this size of buffer for snmp trap?

Comment: Are you using any framework for SNMP requests, such as net-snmp? If so, which one?

Comment: While you ask "why do we need it", I would ask the counterquestion "how do you know you need it?" Clarifying how you figured out that number could help others understand your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SNMP allows PDUs sized up to the MTU of the network. The buffer should be as big as the largest anticipated packet, so it should probably correspond to the MTU, if possible.
For example, Ethernet allows up to 1500 byte frame payloads.

Edit: Ok, here is the formal definition from RFC 3416:

```
The maximum size of an SNMP message is limited to the minimum of:

(1)   the maximum message size which the destination SNMP entity can
     accept; and,

(2)   the maximum message size which the source SNMP entity can
     generate.
```

I interpreted that to be related to the MTU of the network, but of course, if the packets are re-assembled properly after fragmentation, there is no problem in receiving even larger traps.

Maybe, if you are asking "why is the number 65536 in my code", you should ask the person who wrote it?

Comment: when i tested the code, i was able to receive 12000 bytes trap. so that means ip fragments and re-assemble and forwards to udp and then snmp layer. so, do you think trap size should matter as such? i mean, Does snmp talk about limit on size of the trap?